# HP 14cf1 Display strange image

Tags: display

Display liquid crystal leak or broken or wtf. Turned on one day and this is what the display looks like. Under extended warranty but HP they wont cover as they say it was physically damaged and screen is cracked. There is no physical or visible damage...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFHhl.jpg)

Comment: I do not have a good suggestion as (a) it does appear from the picture to be damaged and (b) you are at HP's discretion. Can you take the monitor / machine to a local repair shop and see if they can see damage and then report back to HP under any service number you have from HP?

Comment: That's what a physically broken LCD panel looks like. No standard warranty covers that. The location could indicate a stick or stiff hinge, but you'd have had to torque the screen and cracked it against the hinge if that were the cause.

Answer (score 0):

That's what a physically broken LCD panel looks like. No standard warranty covers that. The location could indicate a stick or stiff hinge, but you'd have had to torque the screen and cracked it against the hinge if that were the cause